# Nginx log entries to multiple files

Tags: nginx, logging

I'd like to log the same access.log entries to separate files, so when a request comes in it should populate a.log and b.log. Is there any way to do this with nginx?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, just have two `access_log` directives in the same block.

Since `access_log` in one block overrides any such directives in outer blocks, you have to copy and paste the directive from the outer block into the inner block if you need to log twice in an inner bock.

Comment: I know, this is ancient, but does it still work? If so, then what is the exact nginx.conf line for it?